# Calculate real DPI of images in a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, tesseract, pypdf

This is breaking my brain. I'm setting up a process to OCR mutipage PDFs with tesseract. I'm extracting the native images with pypdf, running tesseract on each page with PDF output, and joining the pages again with pypdf. The issue is that this is messing with the PDF page sizes.

In this example, pypdf says the page size is 612.24x790.8, but extracting the native png image is 2552x3295 pixels. Essentially, the PDF is supposed to be 300 dpi, but it seems that pypdf extracts images at 72 dpi. So, when I run tesseract on the page, it produces a 35.444inx45.764in PDF instead of what was originally a 8.5inx11in pdf.

I can use imagemagick to convert this back to 300 dpi, but for future documents, I won't know what the dpi should be or what the original page size was. All I seem to be able to get is the 612.24x790.8 size of the PDF.

Is there a way to calculate the dpi of the image from that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the real dpi using `pdfimages -list` from `poppler-utils`. `pdfimages` can extract images too, but has the same issue that everything ends up at 72 dpi.

Its a bit hacky, but I ended up parsing the `pdfimages -list` table to a dict lookup.

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pageDPI = {}
pdfimagesCmd = ["pdfimages", "-list", filepath]
pdfimages = Popen(pdfimagesCmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
# skip the first two lines
lineCount = -2
for line in pdfimages.stdout:
    lineCount += 1
    if lineCount > 0:
        col = re.split("\\s+", line.decode().strip())
        pageDPI[lineCount] = f"{col[12]}x{col[13]}"
```

Once I got the real dpi, I extracted the images with pypdf, ran ImageMagick to convert it back to the correct dpi, ran tesseract, and then merged the PDFs again with pypdf.

```
from PIL import Image
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def process(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if len(stdout) > 0:
        print (stdout.decode())
    if len(stderr) > 0:
        print (stderr.decode())
    return p.returncode

pageOrder = []
pdf_reader = PdfReader(filepath)

page_count = 0
page_total = len(pdf_reader.pages)
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
    page_count += 1
    if len(page.images) != 1:
        raise ValueError(f"ERROR: During OCR prep, PDF page number {page_count} has multiple images.")
    page_rotation = page.get('/Rotate')
    for image in page.images:
        # get native file extension
        ext = os.path.splitext(image.name)[1]
        image_path = os.path.join(convertDir, f"{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}-{page_count}{ext}")
        if os.path.isfile(image_path):
            raise ValueError(f"ERROR: In extracting images for OCR, file already exists: {image_path}.")
        with open(image_path, "wb") as fp:
            fp.write(image.data)

        # fix sizing
        print (f"\tRestoring to {pageDPI[page_count]} dpi...")
        size_cmd = ['convert', '-units', 'pixelsperinch', '-density', pageDPI[page_count], image_path, image_path]
        #print (f"\trunning {' '.join(size_cmd)}")
        size_resp = process(size_cmd)
        if size_resp != 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Error resizing file {image_path}')

        # address image rotation
        if page_rotation:
            print ("\tFixing image rotation...")
            img = Image.open(image_path)
            img_rotate = img.rotate(-abs(page_rotation), expand=1)
            img_rotate.save(image_path)

        page_file = os.path.join(convertDir, f"{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}-{page_count}")
        pageOrder.append(page_file + ".pdf")
        cmd = ["tesseract", image_path, page_file, "pdf"]
        print (f"\t--> reading page {page_count} of {page_total}, {image_path}...")
        resp = process(cmd)
        if resp != 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Error processing file {file}')
        # delete temporary image
        os.remove(image_path)

# Merge back to single PDF
print (f"Merging back to {file}...")
os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(root, "." + file))
merger = PdfWriter()
for pdf_page in pageOrder:
    merger.append(pdf_page)
merger.write(filepath)
merger.close()
if os.path.isfile(filepath) and os.stat(filepath).st_size:
    os.remove(os.path.join(root, "." + file))
    # delete temporary pdf
    for pdf_page in pageOrder:
        os.remove(pdf_page)
```